# Sphere Engine Problem‍ API - Error : Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: no access control allow origin is present

Tags: ajax

I am using sphere-engine api.
i want to send a GET request to have a list of compiler that they have.

according to their documentation.. I can get the list by doing this.

Example of Request (CURL)

```
curl -X GET -H 'Content-Type: application/json'  "http://db4262da.problems.sphere-engine.com/api/v3/compilers?access_token=xxxx"
```

Now I want to do it with an AJAX REQUEST.

this is my code..

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://db4262da.problems.sphere-engine.com/api/v3/compilers?access_token=xxxx",
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function(result, data){
            // var obj = JSON.parse(result);
            // $scope.submitId = obj.id;
            // console.log(obj.id);
        },
    });
```

The problem is . I am always getting this error

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://db4262da.problems.sphere-engine.com/api/v3/compilers?access_token=xxxx. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://heuricode.dev' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 405.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use Sphere Engine API from the level of you Javascript code. Please be aware that your `access_token` would become public. Therefore, everyone would be able to see it and use it.

You should communicate with the Sphere Engine API from the backend of your application. If you want to make asynchronous calls to the Sphere Engine API you should build your own layer. Finally, the asynchronous call could look like this:

```
ajax_call_to_your_application -> your_backend -> Sphere Engine
```